# UCB bandit reward bound

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

The original paper of Auer [1] requires bandit arms to have a reward distribution bounded on [0,1] for the Upper-Confidence-Bound (UCB) theorems to hold. I was wondering how strict this requirement is in practice, i.e. does UCB performs well when this reward bound requirement is not met?

If this requirement **is** strict, I'm aware I could attempt to rescale the rewards. I was however not able to find much pointers on how to rescale a floating point (say an IEEE-754 double precision float) *properly* to a double precision float in [0,1]. With properly, I mean, to retain as much of the features of the reward distribution as possible and to keep the updating of Q values as numerically stable as possible.

[1] Auer, Peter, Nicolo Cesa-Bianchi, and Paul Fischer. "Finite-time analysis of the multiarmed bandit problem." Machine learning 47.2-3 (2002): 235-256.

Answer (score 1):

UCB algorithms work well for more general distributions, though the weighting between the mean and variance may change a bit.  For example in the case where rewards are sampled from a high-dimensional Gaussian process, Srinivas et al. derive near-optimal regret bounds for a UCB algorithm in their paper "Information-Theoretic Regret Bounds for Gaussian Process Optimization in the Bandit Setting".